# Software for visualizing and anotating tree-like data structures

Tags: tree, visualization

I have a tree-like data structure, which I want to visualize and annotate, e.g. I am planning to attached some graphics and text to each node.
Which software do you suggest for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you want to present the results - or whether the visualisation needs to be editable.  If you're happy with a static image then [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) might be a good starting point.